# How a dojox/mobile/view fit to screen size

Tags: css, view, dojo, screen

I am writing a hybrid app, and want to set a background image for login view. So defined a css to set the background image, and hope both width and height are 100%

```
#loginView {
    background-image: url("images/background-2.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

and have a div using dojox.mobile.View

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View" id="loginView" data-dojo-props="selected:true">
    User ID:<input type="text" id="userid"></input> 
    <br/>
    Password:<input type="password" id="password"></input>      
</div>
```

But the result is as attached screen shot: http://pan.baidu.com/share/link?shareid=371078119&uk=2987868974

The dojox view does not automatically fit to screen size, please help advise me how I can make the div/view auto fit to screen width and height (100%), many thanks!

Comment: maybe try `body{height:100%}` in your css

Comment: hi, thanks! I had a style to set body height as 100% just as you pointed, but still remain the same, the div height seems to be wrapped to inner controls. I only have two input fields in the div, then the div height is like height of two inputs' height....

Comment: what if you put the `background-image: url("images/background-2.png");` on the body instead of the div in your css?

Comment: yes, it does work to set the background image on body! thanks for the suggestion! but further more, because I only want to have a specific background image for login view, if set the background image on body, it means all other views also have the background image...

Comment: In my testing, FoamyGuy's suggestion (setting body's height to 100%) works fine. I get the background image of the View filling the entire screen with both Dojo 1.8.3 and 1.9.1, on desktop (Chrome, Firefox) and mobile (Android 4.2 and iOS 6). To be on the safe side, you can set 100% on both html and body: `html,body{height: 100%;}`